# Как в датафрейме найти столбец с наибольшим числом Nan значений и вывести его индекс и количество таких значений

Tags: python, pandas

Работаю с большим csv файлом с помощью pandas. `df.isnull().sum()` выводит все столбцы, а как определить тот, где больше всего пропущенных значений?

Comment: Оксана, вы получили что хотели?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.isnull().sum().idxmax()
```

Название столбца с максимальным количеством пропущенных значений

```
df.isnull().sum().max()
```

Вывод значения максимума в столбце

Answer (score 0):

Есть идея в том что бы пройтись по каждому столбцу, забрать все значения Nan, и присвоить финальное значения для каждого итератора столбца, наполняя ими список, а после вывести максимальное значение списка, например как вариант:

```
   def nan(file_name):
     
    n_Max = #Ваше количество стобцов
    n = 1
    i = 0
    max_equal = []
    with open(file_name, encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
                reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
                for row in reader:
                    if row[f'Row{n}'] == 'Nan': #Цикл проходится по таблице и забирает нужное значение в стобце row[n], ваше имя стобца должно совпадать с именем в таблице
                            row[f'Row{n}'] = i + 1
                    else:
                        continue
                    max_equal.append(row[f'Row{n}'])   
                    n = n + 1 
                print(max(max_equal))        

nan('file_name.csv')
```